# Help! How to make a rope pulling object animation to this model?

Tags: modeling, animation

i need some help.
how to make the yellow rope pulling the front arm goes up and down?
[image]

Comment: I would suggest using Hook modifier, take your rope, make it simple, just 1 vert(control point) at top and one at bottom, hook the bottom one at the specific place of your arm and moving of the arm should pull that rope

Answer (score 3):

This is what you can easily achieve with curve and hook:
[image]

[image]

Way to do this:
Create single vert (easier than making curve), place your single vert in point A, extrude it to point B, convert mesh to curve, add geometry to id and now the good part...
[image]

Make sure that origin point of your arm is in place that will be it's joint...

Select your curve, add hook modifier and choose your arm as object.
Go to edit mode, select vert that is on your arm (point B) and press the button "Assign"...
[image]

That's it, now when you move your arm, rope will change it's shape(arm controls movement, not rope)

Comment: can you mark which one is point A?

Comment: I added 1 picture with point A and point B

Comment: Hi Miko..thank you very much for your lesson. i actually already found a lazy way to do it by using shape key. hehehe...

Comment: Well shape keys are way as well, but I thought that shape keys take more time than this solution